# Image is Blurred - XAML

Tags: c#, .net, image, xaml, render

When I put an image with big dimension on this, the image is blurred. I search in various websites on a "RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode", and the options that appear to me are just "RenderTransform" and "RenderTransformOrigin".

```
<Image Width="249" Height="400" Stretch="Fill">
<Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="http://example.com/example.jpeg" />
</Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: What is the original size of the image? Looks like you are making a bigger one, pixels don't appear from magic, the system has to interpolate new ones when you zoom in, so things will get blurry.

Comment: Hi, well, the size of image is not the best... but is right for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
<Image Width="249" Height="400" Stretch="Fill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="http://example.com/example.jpeg" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```